# Change Text input value on checkbox select

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I am trying to input the `value` of a checkbox into a text input.

Let's say that the input box is empty - you click on the checkbox, and the value assigned to the checbkox is being shown inside the input box.

```
$('input.lowercase').on('change', function(){
      if ( $(this).is(':checked') ) {
$("input.qwer").on("keyup",function () {
    $("input.qwer").html($(this).val());
}); } } );
```

No matter what I do I can't get this to work. Any help?
http://jsfiddle.net/6ycnzrty/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### [EDITED] (As per your needs)

### Demo on <kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6ycnzrty/18/)</kbd>

#### HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="output" value="" />
<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="qwer" value="qwerty">Input value of this checkbox(qwert)
<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="numbers" value="1234567890">Input value of this checkbox(numbers)
<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="asdfg" value="asdfg">Input value of this checkbox(asdfg)
<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="zxcvb" value="zxcvb">Input value of this checkbox(zxcvb)
```

#### JavaScript:

```
$('input.qwer').on('change', function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('.output').val($('.output').val() + $(this).val());
    } else {
        $('.output').val($('.output').val().replace($('.qwer').val(), ''));
    }
});

$('input.numbers').on('change', function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('.output').val($('.output').val() + $(this).val());
    } else {
        $('.output').val($('.output').val().replace($('.numbers').val(), ''));
    }
});

$('input.asdfg').on('change', function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('.output').val($('.output').val() + $(this).val());
    } else {
        $('.output').val($('.output').val().replace($('.asdfg').val(), ''));
    }
});

$('input.zxcvb').on('change', function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('.output').val($('.output').val() + $(this).val());
    } else {
        $('.output').val($('.output').val().replace($('.zxcvb').val(), ''));
    }
});
```

Comment: Quick question, if I add second checkbox with other value, and check it, how can I make those two values exist in the text input box? Because with this solution one checkbox value is being replaced by other one. Appreciate your help!

Comment: Do you want to add two values to one textbox?

Comment: Yes. Basically multiple values from multiple checkboxes added to one textbox. This is embarassing because 2 days ago I had it working and somehow I am unable now to recreate it.

Comment: Okay, I've edited my answer and the link to the fiddle. Let me know if this is what you want.

Comment: It works nicely :-) Is there any way to remove the added value from checkbox on uncheck?

Comment: Ofcourse there is. I have edited my answer again with the link to the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6ycnzrty/7/).

Comment: I am really sorry to bother you but this code removes whole content of the input box when checked. Check 2 checkboxes, uncheck one, and whole content will disappear. On uncheck, it should remove only the text added by itself.

Comment: It's totally fine. And I have edited my answer again. [Check it out](http://jsfiddle.net/6ycnzrty/8/). Let me know, if you need anything else.

Comment: Ok, so let's say we've got this.
http://jsfiddle.net/6ycnzrty/11/
I want to achieve an effect where I can check all 4 boxes, and unchecking any of those will remove only the value from the checked box. For example if I check all the boxes, the value inside will be 1234567890qwerasdfgzxcvb  - and when you uncheck the Numbers checkbox, the input should show qwerasdfgzxcvb - i hope you understand what i mean :) I just want it to dynamically update.

Comment: Okay give me few minutes

Comment: So this is what I have done. [Check it out](http://jsfiddle.net/6ycnzrty/18/) and I will edit my answer again with the new HTML, JavaScript code and the link to the new fiddle.

Comment: And I've updated my answer as well. I am pretty sure, this is exactly what you needed.

Comment: @chipChocolate.py hey do you know how to do it in other way? change textbox value according to user inputted value , ex- like when user enters one, changes one checkbox like :)

Answer (score 2):

Try This :-

```
$('input.qwer').on('change', function(){
   if ( $(this).is(':checked') ) {
     $("input.output").val($(this).val());
   } 
   else{ $("input.output").val("123"); }
});
```

**With above code if checkbox is unchecked then textbox having class 'output' will get its initial view i.e '123',if you don't need this functionality then try this :**

```
$('input.qwer').on('change', function(){
   if ( $(this).is(':checked') ) {
     $("input.output").val($(this).val());
   } 
});
```

**EDIT :-**

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/12ep3Lho/)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var $chk = $('input.qwer').on('change', function () {
    //if the checkbox is checked and output is empty set the value
    if (this.checked && !$output.val()) {
        $output.val(this.value)
    }
});
var $output = $("input.output").on("change", function () {
    //when the value of output is changed as empty and checkbox is checked then set the value to checkbox
    if (!this.value && $chk.is(':checked')) {
        this.value = $chk.val();
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/k4LLzbpt/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input.qwer").on("change",function () {
    if($(this).is(":checked"))
    $("input.output").val($(this).val());
    else
        $("input.output").val("123");
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vikrant47/6ycnzrty/4/)